# Oracle forms - only java output

Tags: oracle, forms, internet-explorer, proxy, jinitiator

When using IExplore 9 and jinitiator to launch some oracle forms, i can only see the java console text output, the GUI actually doesn't start!

More details:

- It's a local https website
- From website once connected you push the button and oracle forms should run
- Once i push the button only java console appears
- Java output actually shows it's connecting to the website and downloads all the files in order to display
- Compared to working example, my output and other working machines got same java output
- IExplore is configured to allow the https site every request "intranet site" and also allows Active-X content and everything..
- Jinitiator plugin is installed in IExplore
- Java JRE 6 also present on the system
- Following other people tips did replace C:\Program Files\oracle\jinitiator_1.3.1.25\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll with new jvm.dll from java 1.6
- Currently using proxy to connect to the website using IExplore and jinitiator set to use browser proxy, connection appears fine, looks like it connects
- using self signe certificate for the proxy connection that i already added to trusted certificates on IExplore
- See some difference when using ssl1.0, ssl1.2 and changing these options in java
- Tried different jvm.dll versions and different java versions also disabled all plugin in IExplore

My question is, how can i see the content of the database I'm trying to join in? Is there a way to use java to connect to the server? how can i see the GUI of what happening inside console?

Thank you

Comment: Internet Explorer... really? Does this happen in other browsers? If you can ditch IE would be recommended, it is known to cause *several* issues.

Comment: Do you see just a `grey screen` as GUI on IE browser?

Comment: *Designed to work on IExplore only!
*No GUI at all! not even a screen or pop up..

Comment: Can you help to solve this Riddle!?@#